# GRUB unknown filesystem error after managing Windows 7 partitions

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, debian, grub

I'm using Debian and Windows 7 located on one HDD, in dual boot. Windows 7 had two partitions (system partition C: and general-use partition G:). Recently I've cut the G partition in size and created new partition F in emptied disk space. I'm pretty sure there was no reboot after that: laptop was on/off in sleep mode for few days. Now after what may be first reboot since partitioning, I get grub `error: unknown filesystem` in Rescue Mode. 
Could those changes in partition be the source of error? How to restore Grub to working state? (Preferably without losing the data from HDD)

[image: pic]

Comment: What file system did this new partition have exactly?  Does Debian have NTFS support?

Comment: New partition is supposedly nfts, though I'm not 100 percent sure now. I don't know if and how Debian supports NFTS, but I guess it does on some level; I always could access files from Win7 NFTS partitions under Debian, if that's the case.

Comment: You need to be sure what file system is being used and if its supported on Debian these are not tall tasks I ask of you.

Comment: Using grub to bootstrap windows? Trying to think about your solution seriously gives me heart burn. Not a solution, but I would delete your debian partition and format it with empty NTFS partition that I would use to store my debian virtual machine image for Virtual Box and use both at the same time! :)